# I got an error decoding from binary to ascii

Tags: python, decode

When I use the following code:

```
import requests

def googleSearch(qu):
    with requests.session() as c:
        url = 'https://www.google.com'
        qu = {'q': qu}
        urllink = requests.get(url, params=qu)
        x=urllink.url
  
        return x
  

x=googleSearch('translation')

print(x)
import urllib.request
site=urllib.request.urlopen(x)
bytes=site.read()

"artificial limit of size: "
"bytes=bytes[0:6000]"


text=bytes.decode("utf8")
print (text)
```

I got the the following errors (running the program again and again):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6116: invalid continuation byte
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6143: invalid continuation byte
```

etc.

So I suppose the "site" file is to big.

When I limit the size of the file to 6000 bytes there is no error"

What is happening? Should I slice the file and treat each slice separately?

Comment: No, the file is not too big. By limiting the file size your program simply doesn't receive the bytes that it is unable to decode.

Comment: You are trying to decode the bytes as utf-8, but apparently the data is in a different encoding.

Comment: If I go to `https://www.google.com/?q=translation` then (sometimes) Google brings Czech user interface _for me_ (e.g. button `Zkusím štěstí` instead of `I'm feeling lucky` etc etc.) despite of my  Windows and Google account  are set to _English_ (maybe  inherited from the current input language in the language bar?). And those Czech words are `cp1250` encoded - despite of the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` header… BTW, the `len(bytes)` returns 13327 so  the file is not too big…